# Is this type of yacc code valid?

Tags: c, macros, yacc

```
%{
#ifdef abc
.
.
. // C declarations
.
%}
.
. //  Yacc Declaration
.
%%
.
. //expected inputs and corresponding actins
.
%%

#endif
```

Although this code compiles for me even then I strongly feel `#ifdef abc` is not placed correctly. Is this type of code valid for Yacc.

I have very little experience in YACC.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt this is valid, instead of trying to trick YACC itself, put the conditional macros in your code.

Comment: @H2CO3 I know that but strange thing is that this code compiles and works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code between `%{` and `%}` is put verbatim at the top of the generated C source file, while the code after the rules is also put verbatim but at the end of the generated file.

So the answer to your question is: Yes, it's correct in both Yacc and the generated source. However, from a readability point of view, the Yacc-code might be considered dubious.